# Use handlebars template in nest js application

Tags: nestjs

I want to use handle bars template in my nest js application:

```html
<!--confirmation.hbs-->
<p>Hello template</p>
```

This file is located in `src/mail/templates/confirmation.hbs`. Also i try to send this template as email:

```js
//mail service
@Injectable()
export class EmailService {
  constructor(private readonly mailerService: MailerService) {}

  public example(): void {
    this.mailerService
      .sendMail({
        to: 'mail', // list of receivers
        from: 'test@nestjs.com', // sender address
        subject: 'Testing Nest MailerModule ✔', // Subject line
        template: './confirmation', 
      })
      .then((r) => {
        console.log(r, 'email is sent');
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log(e, 'error sending email');
      });
  }
}
```

My `app.module.ts` looks:

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    MailerModule.forRoot({
      transport: {
        service: 'Gmail',
        auth: {
          user: '---secret',
          pass: '---secret',
        },
      },
      defaults: {
        from: '"No Reply" <no-reply@localhost>',
      },
      template: {
        dir: __dirname + '/templates',
        adapter: new HandlebarsAdapter(),
        options: {
          strict: true,
        },
      },
    }),
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'postgres',
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 5433,
      username: '-',
      password: '-',
      database: '-',
      entities: [RegisterEntity],
      synchronize: true,
    }),
    AuthenticationModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController, AuthenticationController],
  providers: [AppService, AuthenticationService],
})
```

This is my `main.ts`

```js
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.setGlobalPrefix(CONSTANTS.GLOBAL_PREFIX);
  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

This is my `nest-cli.hbs`

```js
{
  "collection": "@nestjs/schematics",
  "sourceRoot": "src",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "assets": [
      "mail/templates/**/*.hbs"
    ],
    "watchAssets": true
  }
}
```

The email is sent if don't send a template, so the code is working. Trying to send an email template like is my code above i get this error: `TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'templateName' of 'precompile(...)' as it is undefined.` 
 Question: Why i get this issue and how to get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

Your files are located inside `src/mail/templates/`.

But in your module you have `dir: __dirname + '/templates',`.

Here `__dirname` returns `app.module.ts` folder location path which is `src/`.

change

`dir: __dirname + '/templates',`

to

`dir: __dirname + '/mail/templates',`

Answer (score 0):

Since this bug is not yet released [#743](https://github.com/nest-modules/mailer/pull/743) (to this date), I rolled back to previous version:

```
npm i --save @nestjs-modules/mailer@1.6.0 --force
```

Answer (score 0):

For me,this is a template file path issue.
Review your template.dir in your MailerModule config, and compare it to your project "dist" directory.
if your template file path is "dist/templates/template.hbs"
then your template.dir should be `${process.cwd()}/templates`
else if your dist directory is "dist/src/templates/template.hbs" ,which is depend on your compile configs.
then your template.dir config should be join(__dirname, 'templates')

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the nest-cli.json file. You need to specify the output directory in the assets to let nest know where to output your templates files.

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "deleteOutDir": true,
    "assets": [{ "include": "templates/**/*", "outDir": "dist/" }],
    "watchAssets": true
  }
```

My whole nest-cli.json file is like this

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/nest-cli",
  "collection": "@nestjs/schematics",
  "sourceRoot": "src",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "deleteOutDir": true,
    "assets": [{ "include": "templates/**/*", "outDir": "dist/" }],
    "watchAssets": true
  }
}
```